# Data Frame Column Copying resulting in Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I'm trying to copy data over from one Panadas DataFrame into another and I'm getting some strange results. For example if I have:

```py
[In]:
A = {'Types':['Falcon', 'Eagle', 'sparrow'], 
     'Speed':[100, 75, 50]}
df_A = pd.DataFrame(A)

df_B = pd.DataFrame()
df_B['Type'] = df_A['Types']
df_B['tags'] = ['FLCN', 'EGLE', 'SPRW']
df_B['ID'] = [543.76, 534.32, 645.25]

df_A['Tags'] = df_B['tags']
df_A['ID'] = df_B['ID']
df_A
```

What I'm expecting to get is:

```py
[Out]:
    Types   Speed   Tags    ID
0   Falcon  100     FLCN    543.76
1   Eagle   75      EGLE    534.32
2   sparrow 50      SPRW    645.25
```

But what I'm getting instead is:

```py
[Out]:
    Types   Speed   Tags    ID
0   Falcon  100     FLCN    NaN
1   Eagle   75      EGLE    NaN
2   sparrow 50      SPRW    NaN
```

I've tried doing this in a Jupyter Notebook to trouble shoot and received a `TypeError: "'Method' object is not subscriptable"`. Here is an example of the type error that I received:

ex. 2:

```py
[In]:
df_A['ID'] = df_B['ID']

[Out]:
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Once I decided to write a question I wrote the code for these examples in Jupyter and got the expected results without any issue, so I'm stumped.

**Edit to Add:**
I've tried using the following as a work around:

```py
[In]:
df_A['Tags'] = df_B['tags']
df_A = pd.concat(df_A, df_B['ID'], axis = 1)
```

but I'm still getting funky results. With this sample code I end up with:

```py
[Out]:
    Types   Speed   Tags    ID
0   Falcon  100     FLCN    543.76
1   Eagle   75      EGLE    534.32
2   sparrow 50      SPRW    645.25
```

but when I use my larger data set, the results look like this:

```py
[Out]:
    Types   Speed   Tags    ID
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     543.76
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     534.32
2   NaN     NaN     NaN     645.25
3   Falcon  100     FLCN    NaN
4   Eagle   75      EGLE    NaN
5   sparrow 50      SPRW    NaN
```

despite using 'axis=1' as a parameter in pd.concat.

Comment: this works for me, cannot reproduce.

Comment: @Erfan Thanks for trying, I'm having trouble reproducing it myself. It only is happening in the one spot with my actual datasets. I copy multiple columns but only the one is having this issue

Comment: To your workaround perhaps add `ignore_index=True`
`pd.concat([df_A, df_B['tags']], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @viniciusrf1992 THANK YOU! At one point in my code I have ```df_A.index = df_B['Name']``` and when I tried your addition in my code at the original line it didn't work--but, on a hunch I moved ```pd.concat``` to before setting the index and was able to get my desired result.  As a note for anyone that finds this question in the future. I did have to rename all my columns after the concat, but it worked now. I can edit my question to include that but I'd like to give you credit, so if you'd like, you can update your answer and I can select it as the right answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that it somehow helped.

Comment: Please don't add answers inside the question. Instead, post an answer and accept it. This way, future readers will know there is a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each step, with the provided code, I get no NaN neither.

```
import pandas as pd


def print_df_A_df_B(stage, df_A, df_B):
    print(stage, "assignment","\ndf_A\n",df_A,"\ndf_B\n",df_B,"\n")
    pass

A = {'Types':['Falcon', 'Eagle', 'sparrow'], 
     'Speed':[100, 75, 50]}
df_A = pd.DataFrame(A)

df_B = pd.DataFrame()
df_B['Type'] = df_A['Types']
print_df_A_df_B("Type", df_A, df_B)
df_B['tags'] = ['FLCN', 'EGLE', 'SPRW']
df_B['ID'] = [543.76, 534.32, 645.25]

df_A['Tags'] = df_B['tags']
print_df_A_df_B("Tags", df_A, df_B)
df_A['ID'] = df_B['ID']
print_df_A_df_B("ID", df_A, df_B)
```

Out

```
Type assignment 
df_A
      Types  Speed
0   Falcon    100
1    Eagle     75
2  sparrow     50 
df_B
       Type
0   Falcon
1    Eagle
2  sparrow 

Tags assignment 
df_A
      Types  Speed  Tags
0   Falcon    100  FLCN
1    Eagle     75  EGLE
2  sparrow     50  SPRW 
df_B
       Type  tags      ID
0   Falcon  FLCN  543.76
1    Eagle  EGLE  534.32
2  sparrow  SPRW  645.25 

ID assignment 
df_A
      Types  Speed  Tags      ID
0   Falcon    100  FLCN  543.76
1    Eagle     75  EGLE  534.32
2  sparrow     50  SPRW  645.25 
df_B
       Type  tags      ID
0   Falcon  FLCN  543.76
1    Eagle  EGLE  534.32
2  sparrow  SPRW  645.25
```

Perhaps try in your full code: `print(type(df_A['ID']), type(df_B['ID']))` to check if both are `pandas.core.series.Series`.

For your reported workaround perhaps add `ignore_index=True` as `pd.concat([df_A, df_B['tags']], axis=1, ignore_index=True)` and fix the column names thereafter.

Comment: I just checked and they both match: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I get this (Jupiter Notebook). So your code seems to work right?

```
Types   Speed   Tags    ID
0   Falcon  100 FLCN    543.76
1   Eagle   75  EGLE    534.32
2   sparrow 50  SPRW    645.25
```

Comment: Running the sample code is working fine on my end but with the larger code I'm still getting the NaN results.
The code is written the same way but just using different DataFrames. I wrote the sample to simplify the data that is being used and make the question easier to understand